# How to Fix "Upside Down" / "Inverted" / "Flipped" Text in placeholderAttributedString of NSTextField

Tags: swift, macos, nsattributedstring

I've already figured out the solution. However, I couldn't find anything that addressed the problem.

**Problem:**

I wanted to customize the placeholder text in `NSTextField`, but it would appear upside down.

```
let string = "Enter \"Script\" Here"
var attributes: Dictionary<NSAttributedString.Key, Any> = [:]
attributes[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] = NSColor.secondaryLabelColor
attributes[NSAttributedString.Key.font] = NSFont(name: "Arial", size: 15.0)!
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)


self.scriptTextField.placeholderAttributedString = attributedString
```

[image: Upside Down Text]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

I had to add `self.scriptTextField.wantsLayer = true`.

```
let string = "Enter \"Script\" Here"
var attributes: Dictionary<NSAttributedString.Key, Any> = [:]
attributes[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] = NSColor.secondaryLabelColor
attributes[NSAttributedString.Key.font] = NSFont(name: "Arial", size: 15.0)!
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)


self.scriptTextField.placeholderAttributedString = attributedString
self.scriptTextField.wantsLayer = true
```

[image: Right Side Up Text]